# Adding null character after string computation

Tags: c++

I am trying to print string "ans" by directly using

```
cout << ans;
```

Instead of going through loop on each character of string. Here is the complete code I have written (string `ans` and `s` have same size).

PS: The program takes a string and print corresponding number associated to its character of mobile keypad.(like a b c will give 2, d e f will give 3)

(so string `abcdef` will print `222333` that is why string `ans` and `s` will have the same size)

PS: I have written in comments where the problem is.

```
#include<iostream>
char has[]={'2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4','5','5','5','6','6','6','7','7','7','7','8','8','8','9','9','9','9'};
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
    //code
         int t;
         cin>>t; 
         while(t)
         {
            string s,ans;
            int i;
            cin>>s;
            for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            {
                ans[i]=has[s[i]-'a'];
            }
            ans[i]='\0';
            cout<<ans;  // **Does not printing string "ans" Why?****

            for(i=0;i<s.length();i++) 
            cout<<ans[i];  // **printing the string "ans" but using loop**

            cout<<endl;
            //**some other methods I found in forum commented them**
            //string str(ans);
            //cout<<str.c_str();

              t--;
         }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are `ans` and `s` the same size? It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: As posted, your code can not compile. Please provide a [MCVE](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiT3IilhLLOAhVJbBoKHXl0C3AQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=rTT_HsVDk_OwX_WIvwBAqw)

Comment: Please post the **real** code that produces the error and tell us what output you expected. As it is `ans` and `s` are not the same size.

Comment: If you are using a C++ `std::string`, why are you using C style (and ASCII-specific) character handling? This code is *severely* broken on several levels....

Answer (score 4):

A `std::string` is initialized as an empty string. You are accessing `ans` via `operator[]`, but this does not add characters to the string. Accessing non-existing indices this way is undefined behaviour, which unfortunately didn't cause a crash as that would be a hint to the error.

Possible solutions: Initialize the string to the needed length if you want to keep on using `operator[]` or use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to form the needed string.

BTW: `std::string` doesn't need a terminating nul-character.

Comment: @DevSolar: thanks: better wording and cleaner formatting.

Comment: Unlike in many other languages, `std::string` is not an immutable string: there's nothing wrong with simply using `+=` or `std::string::append`. No need to use `std::stringstream` just to add some `char`s. If you want to avoid memory allocations for performance reasons, use `std::string::reserve`

Comment: @KABoissonneault: you're right.  That's why I wrote "possible solutions".  Your solutions are better in this case, ostringstream can be used more generally.

Answer (score 2):

This code is almost a full nonsense.

After `cin >> s`, `s` can be anything (whatever sequence, whatever long of characters: just let your cat to type randomly on the keyboard. The only thing it will not have are ... spaces)

Hence `s[i]-'a'` can be anything from -128 to +127.
Hence `has[s[i]-'a']` is mostly an undefined behavior.
Even if is one of the characters in `h`, `ans[i]` is an "out of bound", being `ans` declared as empty (and I'm really completely unable to figure out what "ans and s are the same size" in your question means.

And after all that, the purpose of what you want to do remain completely obscure ...

Comment: Also, `'a'` is a code smell in itself, as there is no guarantee that letters have consecutive values, or the encoding used for input has the same values as the encoding used for the source code.

Comment: @DevSolar Good point.  Only 0-9 are guaranteed to be consecutive.

Comment: That's depend on the input encode. Unless he's working on a EBCDIC machine, we can assume they are consecutive. Non consecutive alphabetic are pathology, nowadays, not regularity.

Comment: You'd still be facing the issue of input encoding != source encoding.

Comment: @DevSolar: I agree... but -believe me- that's not the real problem he has to solve!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia You are right I am just a beginner to coding and struggling with my basics. To be fair I don't even know about EBCDIC machine , encoding etc... but I guess this is the final forum to clear my basic doubts when I searched for the question on the INTERNET already. Down-voting my question is only give others to look at others problem while this question still remains a question to me. After reading the comments I have already updated the problem, but now chances of getting any answer are really low :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have multiple mistakes in your code

```
// Assuming you're using std::string
string ans; // empty string
string s; // another empty string
cin>>s; // 's' now have some data
char has[]={'2','3','4','5'};
for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    ans[i]=has[s[i]-'a'];// here you might go out of bounds of 'has'
    cout << ans[i] << " ";
}
ans[i]='\0';
cout<<ans;
```

Assuming your input will never cause `has` to go out of bounds (which is undefined behavior)

I'll start with `operator[]` of `std::string`. The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) states that it performs no boundary checks (so your error might not be detected) and when `pos == size()` the behavior is undefined if this character is modified.

Finally you are adding a terminating null symbol to use it with `cout`. This action is redundant. But if you really need a null-terminated string (which is also known as c-string) you can use special function [`string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) which will do the exact thing.

With all that in mind the correct code would look like this:

```
string ans, s;
cin >> s;
char has[]={'2','3','4','5'};
for(unsigned int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
    ans = ans + has[s[i]-'a']; // << concat string and assign
    cout << ans[i] << " ";
}
cout<<ans; // << cout knows how to handle strings
```

Comment: sry, I did not posted the full code earlier...I have edited the code to complete version of it and is producing correct results... However,  I have stated my problem in the updated code

Comment: @mouse: if you say your updated code is producing correct results, did you also try it with input of 50 characters? There's a good chance with the "empty string access", you will get bad result, while this solution will keep on producing the correct result.

Comment: @stefaanv thanks for pointing out the case, but i don't really understand your point as i have tried it with more than 50 characters string of lower alphabets and it is printing the correct result. I don't understand what do you mean by bad result.

Comment: @mouse: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acbeea9cc93cd640 This is your code with t and s filled in.  With 50 characters in s, it crashes.  With the line `ans[i]=has[s[i]-'a'];` replaced by `ans += has[s[i]-'a'];`, there is no problem.  This shows the "undefined behavior", where there seems no problem with short strings, but crash with longer strings.